# Integrated tail function is a CDF

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X\sim F$ with $F$ a distribution function with $F(0)=0$ and $X$ having mean $\mu$.
Define $$G(x)=\frac{1}{\mu}\int_0^x \mathbb P(X>y) ~d y$$
I'm trying to show $G$ is a distribution function. Monotonicity is clear. We have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} G(x)=\frac{1}{\mu}\int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X>y) ~d y=\frac{\mu}{\mu}=1$$
by the integrated tail formula.

Now the problem comes with the convention of $\int_0^a=-\int_a^0$ for $a<0$. If I just do
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} G(x)=\frac{1}{\mu}\int_0^0\mathbb P(X>y) ~d y=0$$
it works but
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} G(x)=-\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{-\infty}^0\mathbb P(X>y) ~d y=-\infty$$
as $\mathbb P(X>y)= 1-F(y)=1$ for all $y<0$.

Comment: $\tilde{G}(x):=G(x)1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ is a cdf.

Comment: $G(0)=0$ and so a valid cdf should be $0$ for $x<0$.

Comment: $G$ is only defined on $[0,\infty)$. This should be clear from $F(0)=0$.